# Looking for References on Script, NppExec plugin in Notepad++

Tags: reference, notepad++, nppexec

I have just used some script for NotePad++ NppExec.

Where can I find references to explain below terms from the excerpt of the script?

It is supposed to be in a single line, but I break it down to 4 lines to reduce horizontal scroll 
Thank you.

```
-ansi -pedantic -Wall -W -Wconversion -Wshadow -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings 
$(FILE_NAME) -o $(NAME_PART).exe & IF ERRORLEVEL 1 
(echo. && echo Syntax errors were found during compiling.) 
ELSE ($(NAME_PART).exe)
```

Answer (score 0):

The text before the first `&` looks like command line options for a compiler. You could look at your compiler's documentation for the this part.

The remainder looks like Microsoft Windows batch commands. Use the `help` command at the command prompt for details.